# Does a dot after numbers have any particular meaning within arithmetic statements?

Tags: r, syntax

I'm maintaining some code where a previous author has used statements like:

```
x <- 1. * a + b
```

or:

```
if (y < 1.e-3)
```

or:

```
z[z < 0.] <- 0
```

or:

```
f <- aa + bb / 2.
```

The dots in these statements aren't appearing within parameter or function names, and they're not appearing within formulas, so I'm having trouble figuring out whether they have any significance. As far as I can tell, similar statements evaluated with constants substituted for the variables don't evaluate any differently.

I thought that perhaps the periods were inserted to coerce the result to a float, but the statements don't seem to be ambiguous in this regard, and I wasn't under the impression that R needed any help in this regard with different numeric types. he only other explanation I can come up with is that the values originally were floats and the previous author got lazy removing the decimal points when they were changed to integers.

Is there any other possible use for the dot that could be relevant, or am I safe cleaning up these statements?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. It merely makes it obvious that a double value is passed, but it's usually a non-issue as R typically assumes these values to be `numeric`s. So, maybe this person wanted to make sure that you are aware of potential floating point issues (esp. if comparisons are made)?

Comment: That's a solid possibility, given the file header comments mention previous trouble with unexpected behaviour with float comparisons in previous versions.

Comment: There is no difference between 23 and 23.; try `identical(23, 23.)`.  To specify an integer type the constant must be suffixed with L as in `23L`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Grothendieck. Could the first example actually be a pointwise .* operator if there's a space between the period and the asterisk? Doesn't explain the other contexts, but I'm shooting from the hip.

Comment: There is no such operator as `.*` and the user cannot define such syntax either.  One could define `%.*%` but that looks quite different.

Comment: The author probably came from a C or C++ background, where an integral number without a dot is assumed to be an `int`. So, for example, `1/2` is `0` (integral division) but `1./2` is `0.5` (floating point division). As the others have noted, this isn't necessary in R.